# goapp fmt source code directory

Tags: go

While following the example for golang on Google App Platform website I've found that it recommends to put the source files straight into the subfolder of the application folder, e.g.

```
app/
  hello/
    hello.go
  app.yaml
```

I can start the app with `goapp serve app`.

But I cannot format the source code. My first guess was `goapp fmt app` - fail. I cannot also build the app: `goapp build app`

```
can't load package: package app: cannot find package "app" in any of:
         ....
         ....
```

Try with GOPATH:

```
GOPATH=`pwd`/app goapp build
```

Not much sense as well

```
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /....
```

I also afraid that installing packages might be cumbersome unless I've discovered a right place to start them or configure GOPATH correctly. Any ideas on how it should look like for Google App Engine Go app?

Comment: Why the `hello` subfolder? As far as I can see, this is not needed nor recommended. Where did you get that from?

Comment: It was provided to me when I've had created the project. This link, I think: https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/_ah/mimic/ziprepo?repo=repos/appengine-try-go&filename=appengine-try-go.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format everything in the application:

```
  goapp fmt ./app/...
```

To build all:

```
 goapp build ./app/...
```

I usually cd to the directory containing app.yaml so that I can:

```
 goapp serve
 goapp fmt ./...
```

and so on.